Error with Pusher in Laravel React "not foud pusher"
I'm working on a Laravel application that uses Pusher for real-time event broadcasting. I keep encountering this error in BroadcastManager when trying to access the /broadcasting/auth route:
Class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found
http://localhost:8080/broadcasting/auth
The package appears to be installed correctly, confirmed with: composer show pusher/pusher-php-server
My config/broadcasting.php :
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'useTLS' => true,
    ],
],```

I have change my route in my config/app.php :

```App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,```


My version : 
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0",
"laravel/framework": "^7.29",


